# Does the Appstore store a registered user's address?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-appstore, xcode

For example would it be possible for a retailer to have a user download their app, make an in-app purchase and have it sent directly to them without requiring the user to enter an address?

Answer (score 1):

Apple does store the registered user's address and uses it for it's own purposes (see: (Physical) Apple Store app), but it does not disclose any of this information to third parties. I've never seen In-App Purchases used for physical goods, and I highly doubt Apple will provide a developer/publisher with user information to send physical goods.